# Tomcat manager/html is not available?

Tags: tomcat, manager-app

Hi I just installed Tomcat and and am trying to get it up and running however whenever I try to navigate to manager/html it gives me this error "The requested resource (/manager/html) is not available".

The homepage, /docs, /examples all work fine and my logs show nothing. How do I fix this? I'm using Tomcat 6.0.20 and JDK 1.6.0_21 on Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 30):

You have to check if you have the folder with name `manager` inside the folder `webapps` in your tomcat.

```
Rubens-MacBook-Pro:tomcat rfanjul$ ls -la webapps/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   8 rfanjul  staff   272 21 May 12:20 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 rfanjul  staff   476 21 May 12:22 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 rfanjul  staff  6148 21 May 12:20 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  19 rfanjul  staff   646 17 Feb 15:13 ROOT
drwxr-xr-x  51 rfanjul  staff  1734 17 Feb 15:13 docs
drwxr-xr-x   6 rfanjul  staff   204 17 Feb 15:13 examples
drwxr-xr-x   7 rfanjul  staff   238 17 Feb 15:13 host-manager
drwxr-xr-x   8 rfanjul  staff   272 17 Feb 15:13 manager
```

After that you will be sure that you have this permmint for you user in the file `conf/tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="test" password="test" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
```

restart tomcat and stat tomcat again.

```
sh bin/shutdown.sh 
sh bin/startup.sh
```

I hope that will works fine for you.

Comment: What if the folder is not there? Is there a way to add it later on i.e. after tomcat installation?

Comment: Donwload the manager admin dependency `sudo apt-get install tomcat6-admin`.

Comment: I worked from NetBeans, guess roles weren't properly defined..thanks.

Comment: If the "manager" folder is not there on Windows (or any other OS), you can manually copy it from the tomcat release zip file from the apache website. Try to grab the right version.

Comment: It happened to me when I was creating a server inside Eclipse. Eclipse created a temporary server (in a temp directory). But in that temp directory, subfolder "manager" is not there. So I manually copied "manager" folder from the original zip file, and then manager console started to work.

Answer (score 11):

You have to enable access first: [Configuring Manager Application Access](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access)

Answer (score 6):

I had the situatuion when tomcat manager did not start. I had this exception in my logs/manager.DDD-MM-YY.log:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter CSRF
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        ...
```

This exception was raised because I used a version of tomcat that hadn't CSRF prevention filter. Tomcat 6.0.24 doesn't have the CSRF prevention filter in it. The first version that has it is the 6.0.30 version (at least. according to the changelog). As a result, Tomcat Manager was uncompatible with version of Tomcat that I used. I've digged description of this issue here: http://blog.techstacks.com/.m/2009/05/tomcat-management-setting-up-tomcat/comments/

Steps to fix it:

1. Check version of tomcat installed by running "sh version.sh" from
   your tomcat/bin directory
2. Download corresponding version of tomcat
3. Stop tomcat
4. Remove your webapps/manager directory and copy manager application
   from distributive that you've downloaded.
5. Start tomcat

Now you should be able to access tomcat manager.

Answer (score 2):

My problem/solution is very embarrassing but who knows... perhaps it happened to someone else:

My solution: **Turn off proxy**

For the past two hours I've been wondering why my manager would not load. (the root was cached so it loaded). I had set the browser's proxy to proxy traffic to my house. :/

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't log in to the manager app, even though my tomcat-users.xml file was set up correctly. The problem was that tomcat was configured to get users from a database. An employee who knew how this all worked left the company so I had to track this all down.

If you have a web application with something like this in the projects web.xml:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>manager</role-name>
</security-role>
```

You should be aware that this is using the same system for log ins as tomcat! So where ever your manager role user(s) are defined, that is where you should define your manager-gui role and user.
In server.xml I found this:

```
 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
    driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
    connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/<DBName>?user=<DBUser>&amp;password=<DBPassword>"
    userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
    userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" />
```

That tells me there is a database storing all the users and roles. This overrides the tomcat-users.xml file. Nothing in that file works unless this Realm is commented out. The solution is to add your tomcat user to the users table and your manager-gui role to the user_roles table:

```
insert into users (user_name, user_pass) values ('tomcat', '<changeMe>');
insert into user_roles (user_name, role_name) values ('tomcat', 'manager-gui');
```

You should also have a "manager-gui" rolename in the roles table. Add that if it doesn't exist. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Your website is blank because **ROOT** directory is missing from your `../webapps` folder. Refer to [tomcat documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_override_the_default_home_page_loaded_by_Tomcat.3F) for the specific location on where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the folder was _Manager.
After I renamed it to Manager it worked.

Now, I see login popup and I enter credentials from conf/tomcat-users.xml, It all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After entering the roles and users in tomcat-users still if does not work make sure your tomact server location point to the right server location

Comment: I mean server location under eclipse default it might refer to some other kind of use metag-data. Select user Tomcat installation in eclipse

Comment: If you are using tomcat 7 or above use add below to the tomcat-users file                               <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue today. I am using Centos7, the solution was to install ***tomcat-admin-webapp*** package.

```
yum install tomcat-webapps tomcat-admin-webapps
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same and found I'd wrongly commented out the valve in webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml. I'd put the comment 1 line early which meant it was inside the  tag, which probably confused the parser.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in my ./META-INF/context.xml

delete below line, instead of commenting out

<Valve className="org.apache.catlina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"

allow="127.\d+.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />

This works fine with me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

Once try by replacing localhost to your 'computer name' i.e, `http://localhost:8080` to `http://system09:8080`

Comment: Doesn't make any sense because your machine name is not a fully qualified domain...