# Not loading manager/html of apache-tomcat-8.0.17

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, configuration, server

I added a user `'root'` in `tomcat-user.xml` with manager role, like below

```xml
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui" />  
    <role rolename="manager-script" />  
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>  
    <role rolename=" manager-status" />  

    <user username="root" password="root"  
roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,admin-gui,manager-status" />
```

referring to  **[apache-tomcat website](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)** and I restarted apache-tomcat 8.0.17 through eclipse IDE; please find **server log** below

```
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.17
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jan 9 2015 15:58:59 UTC
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.17.0
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_05-b05
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\nithin\workspaceEclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         E:\AAA_DEV_DONT_DEL\SERV\apache-tomcat-8.0.17\apache-tomcat-8.0.17
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\nithin\workspaceEclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=E:\AAA_DEV_DONT_DEL\SERV\apache-tomcat-8.0.17\apache-tomcat-8.0.17
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\nithin\workspaceEclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\AAA_DEV_DONT_DEL\SERV\apache-tomcat-8.0.17\apache-tomcat-8.0.17\endorsed
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: 
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;
    C:\Users\nithin\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;
;E:\AAA_DEV_DONT_DEL\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools;
E:\AAA_DEV_DONT_DEL\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools;
E:\AAA_DEV_DONT_DEL\apache-ant-19\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;.
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 757 ms
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.17
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 18, 2015 11:16:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 464 ms
```

but while hitting **`http://127.0.01:8080/manager/html`** or **`http://localhost:8080/manager/html`** it shows **404 error**; but I can able to create an dynamic web project in eclipse and deploy using `run as> run in server` option. I don't have any proxy settings in my machine and no other server is running simultaneously.

[image: no proxy settings]
[image: web url hitting]

Anymore changes required to get manager/html in version - 8.0.17?
**or** 
Have I done anything wrong in configuration?

I found similar Q&A in stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535078/tomcat-manager-html-is-not-available) but doesn't helped me to solve problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click on your server in the server view.
Go into "server locations" and select "Use tomcat installation".
If it's grayed, right clik on your server, properties>general and click "switch location".
[Tomcat started in Eclipse but unable to connect to http://localhost:8085/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280064/tomcat-started-in-eclipse-but-unable-to-connect-to-http-localhost8085)

Comment: Thanks Vincent, its helped me.. :) and do you know why this happened? Isn't tomcat running in full-mode with eclipse?

Comment: Mmmmh how exactly it works, no. I suppose eclipse creates something like a "virtual server" in order to deploy only the webapps you ask. And if you use the real base installation directory, the application manager is usable.

Comment: It is not straight forward when you invoke Tomcat from within Eclipse. Please read the FAQ section at https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ

It explains how if you start Tomcat from within Eclipse, the binaries of original directories of Tomcat are used, but the web apps etc are stored separately in the Eclipse Workspace.